# How to list Processes started by multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

While attempting to store `multiprocessing`'s **process** instance in `multiprocessing` list-variable 'poolList` I am getting a following exception:

`SimpleQueue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`

The reason why I would like to store the PROCESS instances in a variable is to be able to terminate all or just some of them later (if for example a PROCESS freezes). If storing a PROCESS in variable is not an option I would like to know how to get or to list all the PROCESSES started by `mutliprocessing` POOL. That would be very similar to what `.current_process()` method does. Except `.current_process` gets only a single process while I need all the processes started or all the processes currently running.

Two questions:

1. Is it even possible to store an instance of the **Process** (as a result of `mp.current_process()`
2. Currently I am only able to get a single process from inside of the function that the process is running (from inside of `myFunct()` using `.current_process()` method).

Instead I would like to to list all the processes currently running by `multiprocessing`. How to achieve it?

---

```
import multiprocessing as mp

poolList=mp.Manager().list()

def myFunct(arg):
    print 'myFunct(): current process:', mp.current_process()

    try: poolList.append(mp.current_process())
    except Exception, e: print e

    for i in range(110):
        for n in range(500000):
            pass
        poolDict[arg]=i
    print 'myFunct(): completed', arg, poolDict

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=2)
myArgsList=['arg1','arg2','arg3']

pool=Pool(processes=2)
pool.map_async(myFunct, myArgsList)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're creating a managed `List` object, but then letting the associated `Manager` object expire.
2. `Process` objects are shareable because they aren't pickle-able; that is, they aren't simple.
3. Oddly the `multiprocessing` module doesn't have the equivalent of `threading.enumerate()` -- that is, you *can't* list all outstanding processes.  As a workaround, I just store procs in a list.  I never `terminate()` a process, but do `sys.exit(0)` in the parent.  It's rough, because the workers will leave things in an inconsistent state, but it's okay for smaller programs
4. To kill a frozen worker, I suggest: 1) worker receives "heartbeat" jobs in a queue every now and then, 2) if parent notices worker A hasn't responded to a heartbeat in a certain amount of time, then `p.terminate()`.   Consider restating the problem in another SO question, as it's interesting.

To be honest the `map` stuff is much easier than using a Manager.

Here's a Manager example I've used.  A worker adds stuff to a shared list. Another worker occasionally wakes up, processes everything on the list, then goes back to sleep. The code also has verbose logs, which are essential for ease in debugging.

### source

```
# producer adds to fixed-sized list; scanner uses them

import logging, multiprocessing, sys, time


def producer(objlist):
    '''
    add an item to list every sec; ensure fixed size list
    '''
    logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    logger.info('start')
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return
        msg = 'ding: {:04d}'.format(int(time.time()) % 10000)
        logger.info('put: %s', msg)
        del objlist[0]
        objlist.append( msg )


def scanner(objlist):
    '''
    every now and then, run calculation on objlist
    '''
    logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    logger.info('start')
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return
        logger.info('items: %s', list(objlist))


def main():
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(
            level=logging.INFO
    )
    logger.info('setup')

    # create fixed-length list, shared between producer & consumer
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    my_objlist = manager.list( # pylint: disable=E1101
        [None] * 10
    )

    multiprocessing.Process(
        target=producer,
        args=(my_objlist,),
        name='producer',
    ).start()

    multiprocessing.Process(
        target=scanner,
        args=(my_objlist,),
        name='scanner',
        ).start()

    logger.info('running forever')
    try:
        manager.join() # wait until both workers die
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    logger.info('done')


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your example! But I don't see how it relates to the question asked. I would like to know how to store the PROCESS instances so they could be terminated later using `processInstance.terminate()` `multiprocessing` method. If storing the PROCESS instances is not possible then I would like to find a way to get a list of all the PROCESS instances started by `multiprocessing` Pool with the same goal: to terminate all or some.

Comment: @Sputnix thanks for the feedback.  I've added some commentary into the code, I hope it helps!

Comment: you can get all process by multiprocessing.active_children() please modify your answer and can use p.terminate()

Answer (score 6):

To list the processes started by a Pool()-instance(which is what you mean if I understand you correctly), there is the pool._pool-list. And it contains the instances of the processes.

However, it is not part of the documented interface and hence, really should not be used. 
BUT...it seems a little bit unlikely that it would change just like that anyway. I mean, should they stop having an internal list of processes in the pool? And not call that _pool?
And also, it annoys me that there at least isn't a get processes-method. Or something.
And handling it breaking due to some name change should not be that difficult.

But still, use at your own risk:

```
from multiprocessing import pool

# Have to run in main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create 3 worker processes
    _my_pool = pool.Pool(3)

    # Loop, terminate, and remove from the process list
    # Use a copy [:] of the list to remove items correctly
    for _curr_process in _my_pool._pool[:]:
        print("Terminating process "+ str(_curr_process.pid))
        _curr_process.terminate()
        _my_pool._pool.remove(_curr_process)

    # If you call _repopulate, the pool will again contain 3 worker processes.
    _my_pool._repopulate_pool()
    for _curr_process in _my_pool._pool[:]:
        print("After repopulation "+ str(_curr_process.pid))
```

The example creates a pool and manually terminates all processes.

It is important that you remember to delete the process you terminate from the pool yourself i you want Pool() to continue working as usual.

_my_pool._repopulate increases the number of working processes to 3 again, not needed to answer the question, but gives a little bit of behind-the-scenes insight.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can get all active process and perform action based on name of process
e.g

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, name="refresh-reports")
```

and then

```
for p in multiprocessing.active_children():
   if p.name == "foo":
      p.terminate()
```